# Не обрабатывается второй INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, lampp

В чём суть, в сборке денвера, всё идёт по маслу, а вот на LAMPP не обрабатывается второй запрос, php поставил 5.6.

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password) 
VALUES('$login','$password')");
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tasters SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

В таблице users есть поле id с A_I, и такое же поле в tasters, но без A_I, оба обозначил как ИНДЕКС.
Таблицы созданы заранее таким образом:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`login` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
`status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

И:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasters` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`patronymic` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`sex` int(11) NOT NULL,
`birth` date NOT NULL,
`salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
`marital_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
`children` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: INSERT и SET???

Comment: @MikeWaters по сути оно не слишком отличается: https://stackoverflow.com/a/861729   Хотя возможно у меня не стоит необходимого расширения MySQL

Comment: попробуйте через values

Comment: @MikeWaters     Как-то так? 
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tasters (id) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID()')");
Не отрабатывает.

Comment: а зачем ставить id? вам нужно связать таблицы? добавьте поле user в таблицу tasters и вставляйте туда id user'a. Так из tasters получите доступ к users

Comment: SELECT что-небудь FROM users WHERE id = SELECT user FROM tasters WHERE id = @value (В MySQL мб иначе)

Comment: @MikeWaters Да, мне таблицы связать надо, а вот запрос я не догнал, сложновато что-то.
У меня в таблице users есть поле id с A_I, такое же и в tasters, но без A_I, оба обозначил как ИНДЕКС

Comment: Интересно было бы взглянуть на схемы таблиц. Может быть есть какие-то ограничения, которые не позволяют выполнить второй запрос? Вы пробовали выполнить запросы через консольный клиент mysql?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин добавил запросы по которым сделал таблицу. А с консолью клиента mysql я не знаю как работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я определил в чём проблема, так как в таблице tasters все поля NOT NULL второй запрос не мог корректно выполниться. После того, как я указал их все NULL, кроме поля 'id', вторая вставка была успешно выполнена.